# Make voice calls between two clients using telegram api in C# Program

Tags: c#, telegram

I am building a desktop application using C# & WinForms.The app is for sending and receiving both messages and voice calls between two clients using telegram API.I was able to perform the Send and Receive messages part using the WTelegramClient library But i am stuck at the making voice calls part.
if you know any library that will help me; please tell me how I can do so.
Note that i am also using dotnet framework 4 not dotnet Core.

I tried making voice call with the WTelegramClient library but it did not help, later on I found out that this library does not support sending and receiving voice calls.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.